# Break a long string into lines with proper word wrapping

Tags: java, regex

```
 String original = "This is a sentence.Rajesh want to test the application for the word split.";
 List matchList = new ArrayList();
 Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(".{1,10}(?:\\s|$)", Pattern.DOTALL);
 Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(original);
 while (regexMatcher.find()) {
     matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
 }
 System.out.println("Match List "+matchList);
```

I need to parse text into an array of lines that do not exceed 10 characters in length and should not have a break in word at the end of the line.

I used below logic in my scenario but the problem it is parsing to the nearest white space after 10 characters if there is a break at end of line

for eg: The actual sentence is "**This is a sentence.Rajesh want to test the application for the word split.**" But after logic execution its getting as below.

Match List [This is a , nce.Rajesh , want to , test the , pplication , for the , word , split.]

Comment: Assuming you want this in Groovy?  You make no mention of Groovy apart from in the tag...

Comment: You mean the 10th character should not be a <space>? What if it is a space?

Comment: What happens if there is a word that's longer than 10 characters all by itself? Should it be split in the middle? For example, should `"quickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"` become `{"quickbrown","foxjumpsov", "erthelazyd", "og"}`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the output to be - could you specify what how you would like your example sentence to be split?

Comment: @amaidment My requirement is I need to restrict the number of characters in 1 line to less than or equal to 100 characters with out breaking the word.If the word at the end of the 100 the character is breaking we need to add this word in the next line.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Good question my actual requirement is for 100 characters but just for sample reference I mentioned it as 10 character.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so I've managed to get the following working, with max line length of 10, but also splitting the words that are longer than 10 correctly!

```
String original = "This is a sentence. Rajesh want to test the applications for the word split handling.";
List matchList = new ArrayList();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(.{1,10}(?:\\s|$))|(.{0,10})", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(original);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
  matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
System.out.println("Match List "+matchList);
```

This is the result:

```
This is a 
sentence. 
Rajesh want 
to test 
the 
applicatio
ns word 
split 
handling.
```

Comment: if you want to include line breaks then : "(.{1,10}(?:\\s\\n|$))|(.{0,10})"

Comment: that's great to use regular expression! but it is hard to add '-' between the broken words...

Comment: sorry i don't understand?

Comment: `This is a `  
`sentence.`  
`Rajesh want `  
`to test `  
`the `  
`applicati-`  
`ons word `  
`split `  
`handling.`

Answer (score 2):

This question was tagged as Groovy at some point. Assuming a Groovy answer is still valid and you are not worried about preserving multiple white spaces (e.g. '  '):

```
def splitIntoLines(text, maxLineSize) {
    def words = text.split(/\s+/)
    def lines = ['']
    words.each { word ->
        def lastLine = (lines[-1] + ' ' + word).trim()
        if (lastLine.size() <= maxLineSize)
            // Change last line.
            lines[-1] = lastLine
        else
            // Add word as new line.
            lines << word
    }
    lines
}

// Tests...
def original = "This is a sentence. Rajesh want to test the application for the word split."

assert splitIntoLines(original, 10) == [
    "This is a",
    "sentence.",
    "Rajesh",
    "want to",
    "test the",
    "application",
    "for the",
    "word",
    "split."
]
assert splitIntoLines(original, 20) == [
    "This is a sentence.",
    "Rajesh want to test",
    "the application for",
    "the word split."
]
assert splitIntoLines(original, original.size()) == [original]
```

Answer (score 1):

I avoided regex as is doesn't pull the weight. This code word-wraps, and if a single word is more than 10 chars, breaks it. It also takes care of excess whitespace.

```
import static java.lang.Character.isWhitespace;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String original =
    "This is a sentence.Rajesh want to test the application for the word split.";
  final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(original.trim());
  final List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (true) {
    b.delete(0, indexOfFirstNonWsChar(b));
    if (b.length() == 0) break;
    final int splitAt = lastIndexOfWsBeforeIndex(b, 10);
    matchList.add(b.substring(0, splitAt).trim());
    b.delete(0, splitAt);
  }
  System.out.println("Match List "+matchList);
}
static int lastIndexOfWsBeforeIndex(CharSequence s, int i) {
  if (s.length() <= i) return s.length();
  for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) if (isWhitespace(s.charAt(j-1))) return j;
  return i;
}
static int indexOfFirstNonWsChar(CharSequence s) {
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) if (!isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) return i;
  return s.length();
}
```

Prints:

```
Match List [This is a, sentence.R, ajesh, want to, test the, applicatio, n for the, word, split.]
```

Comment: My requirement is I need to restrict the number of characters in 1 line to less than or equal to 100 characters with out breaking the word.If the word at the end of the 100 the character is breaking we need to add this word in the next line