# How to Split a string in java based on limit

Tags: java, string, split

I have following String and i want to split this string into number of sub strings(by taking ',' as a delimeter) when its length reaches 36. Its not exactly splitting on 36'th position

```
      String message = "This is some(sampletext), and has to be splited properly";
```

**I want to get the output as two substrings follows:**
1. **'This is some (sampletext)'

2. 'and  has to be splited properly'**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: split by white space then concatenate according to the length limit.

Comment: There isn't API in Java to do this, so you'll have to come up with an algorithm. Have you tried it? What problems were you having?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Break a long string into lines with proper word wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702367/break-a-long-string-into-lines-with-proper-word-wrapping)

Comment: What do you expect the output to be for "Improbalistically long word in a sentence"?

Comment: Isn't the last split unnecessary, i.e., shouldn't the output be `'This is some' , 'sample text and' , 'has to be', 'splited properly'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on regex:

```
    String s = "This is some sample text and has to be splited properly";
    Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile(".{1,15}\\b");
    Matcher m = splitPattern.matcher(s);
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        stringList.add(m.group(0).trim());
    }
```

Update:
trim() can be droped by changing the pattern to end in space or end of string:

```
    String s = "This is some sample text and has to be splited properly";
    Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("(.{1,15})\\b( |$)");
    Matcher m = splitPattern.matcher(s);
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        stringList.add(m.group(1));
    }
```

group(1) means that I only need the first part of the pattern (.{1,15}) as output.

.{1,15} - a sequence of any characters (".") with any length between 1 and 15 ({1,15})

\b - a word break (a non-character before of after any word)

( |$) - space or end of string

In addition I've added () surrounding .{1,15} so I can use it as a whole group (m.group(1)).
Depending on the desired result, this expression can be tweaked.

*Update*:
If you want to split message by comma only if it's length would be over 36, try the following expression:

```
Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("(.{1,36})\\b(,|$)");
```

Comment: This solution does not handle the end of the sentence correctly (it introduces a superfluous split between the last two words).

Comment: Actually, it does split the sentence in the way the OP requested. Although I still think the last split is unnecessary.

Comment: @eljenso The last split can be avoided by using Pattern.compile(".{1,16}\\b"), but I put 1,15 because it fits the request.

Comment: Yes, nice. Still, I am amazed that, besides my own answer which I think also works (but feel free to correct me), this is the only other 'serious' answer.

Comment: @tibtof, Thanks again for your answer. Can you explain me what this  (".{1,15}\\b")  expression does exactly.

Comment: @Jagadeesh Sure, you're welcome. I'll edit the answer and add explanations.

Comment: @tibtof, can you help me with the above scenario, i have updated my query. Now ',' is the only delimeter we have.

Comment: If you want to split it only by "," you can use String[] substrings = message.split(",");

Comment: If you don't want to split by every comma, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I can think of is to make a function that iterates through the string. In the function you could keep track of whitespace characters, and for each 16th position you could add a substring to a list based on the position of the last encountered whitespace. After it has found a substring, you start anew from the last encountered whitespace. Then you simply return the list of substrings.

Answer (score 3):

This should work on all inputs, except when there are sequences of chars without whitespace longer than 16. It also creates the minimum amount of extra Strings by indexing into the original one.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    String message = "This is some sample text and has to be splited properly";
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    int start = 0;
    while (start + 16 < message.length())
    {
      int end = start + 16;
      while (!Character.isWhitespace(message.charAt(end--)));
      result.add(message.substring(start, end + 1));
      start = end + 2;
    }
    result.add(message.substring(start));
    System.out.println(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tidy answer:

```
String message = "This is some sample text and has to be splited properly";

String[] temp = message.split("(?<=^.{1,16}) ");
String part1 = message.substring(0, message.length() - temp[temp.length - 1].length() - 1);
String part2 = message.substring(message.length() - temp[temp.length - 1].length());
```

Comment: Can you explain how does it works! I've never seen a split function like this!

Comment: This crashes on empty String, does not work on strings shorter than 16, and the recursive step is missing.

Comment: @eljenso The (obvious) code needed to protect against bad input had been (obviously) omitted, leaving just the code important to the answer, which is quite normal for stackoverflow answers.

Comment: A string shorter than 16 is (obviously) not "bad input". Also, the interesting part here would be the recursive step, which is omitted for some (non-obvious) reason. The devil -- certainly with regexps -- is in the details (see [tibtof's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10735971/30316)). Just throwing a regexp at the OP won't help him. So I disagree that this is "just the code important to the answer."

Answer (score 2):

If you have a simple text as the one you showed above (words separated by blank spaces) you can always think of [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). Here's some simple code working for your case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String message = "This is some sample text and has to be splited properly";
        while (message.length() > 0) {
            String token = "";
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(message);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String nt = st.nextToken();
                String foo = "";
                if (token.length()==0) {
                    foo = nt;
                }
                else {
                    foo = token + " " + nt;
                }
                if (foo.length() < 16)
                    token = foo;
                else {
                    System.out.print("'" + token + "' ");
                    message = message.substring(token.length() + 1, message.length());
                    break;
                }
                if (!st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    System.out.print("'" + token + "' ");
                    message = message.substring(token.length(), message.length());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nope. The last word is dropped from the result, amongst other issues.

Comment: You were right, i wrote the code quite quickly and missed the last word... Now it works fine! What i actually wanted to show you was the StringTokenizer class which can be really useful while working with Strings.